# Calculating the time difference with seconds

Tags: java, time

Here I have got the code part which counts the difference between two times(time1,time2). 
How can I add seconds to it and convert 60sec to one minute?

I assume there is a simpler way to deal with it, but I am studying with book for beginners so I'd like to get the answer in the same way as the hours and minutes are calculated here.

```
  hours=time2/100-time1/100;
  mins=time2%100-time1%100;

  hours=mins>0?hours:hours-1;
  mins=mins>0?mins:mins+60;
```

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java

Comment: What is the unit of `time1` and `time2`?

Comment: Try Joda Time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134927/difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates-using-joda-time

Comment: Use an API instead, e.g. [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)

Comment: Why are you dividing by 100 to get hours?

Comment: Joda = Yoda. Powerful jedi you will be!...

Comment: if time1 and time2 is in millisec then
Short minutes = (short) ((time2-time1) / (60 * 1000));

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        long startTime = sdf.parse("10:00:00").getTime();
        long endTIme = sdf.parse("11:00:00").getTime();
        long duration = endTIme - startTime;

        int seconds = (int) (duration / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = (int) ((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assume you have implemented the time as a number like `1234` is `12:34`  In this case it is easier to parse each time and compare.

```
int mins1 = time1 / 100 * 60 + time1 % 100;
int mins2 = time2 / 100 * 60 + time2 % 100;
int diff = mins2 - mins1;
```

> i want to do is input number 123456 which would be equal to 12:34:56

To handle seconds, you can do.

```
int secs1 = time1 / 10000 * 60 * 60 + time1 /100 % 100 * 60 + time1 % 100;
int secs2 = time2 / 10000 * 60 * 60 + time2 /100 % 100 * 60 + time2 % 100;
int diffInSec = secs1 - secs2;
```

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup
Input number is like 1234, not 12:34, and what i want to do is input number 123456 which would be equal to 12:34:56, then find the difference