# Joda - Infer timeZone by only having dateTime in format "hh:mm:ss"

Tags: java, jodatime

So I have localTime string coming to the server in the format of "hh:mm:ss".
Is there a way to determine the time zone of the client?

So far I can convert the string to joda DateTime using DateTimeFormatter and get the offset in relation to timeZone UTC but this might not be accurate as there will be a delay between the timeStamp taken on the client and the time that the calculation will take place at on the server (e.g. if time sent by client is 11:59:59 +01:00 in it arrived with 2 secs delay on the server the calculation will have roughly the following form: 11:59:59 - 11:00:01 = 0 hours offset which is wrong).

Any suggestions other than forcing the client to send timeZone instead of localTime?

Comment: Don't use only the hours when doing the subtraction.  11:59:59-11:00:01 should give you a 3598-second offset, not a 0-hour offset.  Then when you convert 3598 seconds to hours, you round it to the nearest hour.  That will work as long as there isn't a 30-minute delay in communication, and if there is you've got other problems.

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no way* in which you can calculate the timezone given a local time.  You *can* calculate the offset from UTC, but that's not the same thing as the timezone.

If you want a user's timezone then your best bet is to work from the IP address as that is more likely to give you a location.

Comment: In that case don't you need an exhaustive list of all the timeZones? How's that work? Can you give more details?

Comment: More than that you'll need an exhaustive list of all locations and then map them back to timezones.  Not the simplest of procedures but if you want accurate timezone information then this is the easiest way to obtain it.  A google search for 'geolocation from IP address' will give you any number of services which you can either use or model your own on.

Answer (score 0):

If the error margin is not greater than a few minutes, then you can subtract the UTC time from the received local time and round to the nearest hour to get the offset. You can probably use Minutes.minutesBetween, then divide by 60.0 and round. If you're concerned about :30 and :45 time zones, then you can divide by 15.0, round and multiply by 15 to get the offset in minutes.

However, once you have the offset, there may not be a unique time zone that uses it. And the list of time zones that correspond to that offset depends on the full date (because of DST). So if you really want the time zone, it is better to have the client send it.

Also see [difference in seconds between two dates using joda time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134927/difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates-using-joda-time) and [How can I determine a timezone by the UTC offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274743/how-can-i-determine-a-timezone-by-the-utc-offset)