# Format string containing date

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I receive string from a server that contains date in this format (**2014-06-04 10:26:06**).

I want to convert it to date and apply this date format to it

```
SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

This is what i have at the moment, but its not working.

```
            String formattedDate = longDateFormat.format(messageGSON.getCreated());
            viewHolder.textViewMessageDate.setText(formattedDate);
```

I cant seem to find a solution, i think im missing a a step there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing date with Joda with time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624992/parsing-date-with-joda-with-time-zone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

1) `parse()` String to `Date`

2) `format()` that `Date` to String

```
String formattedDate = longDateFormat.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(messageGSON.getCreated()));
viewHolder.textViewMessageDate.setText(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Legend! worked like a dream, had to surround it with try/catch!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `parse()` `String` to `Date`, and then `format()` `Date` to `String`